# On Windows, how to determine route for IP destination?

Tags: windows, networking, ip, routing

How can I determine the IP route taken for a specific IP destination (without looking at "route print" and figuring it out manually)?

In OS X there's `route get 1.2.34` and in Linux there's `/sbin/ip route get 1.2.3.4`. Is there anything like that on Windows?

Comment: if you are willing to use Powershell you can use the  Get-NetRoute cmdlet, 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826126.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep. Open a command line and type `tracert 1.2.3.4`

Comment: Heh, good point. Not an optimal solution, since it does query the network for something you know locally, but for the most part, gives me the information I need.

Comment: @Ilya: Using `-d` (no resolve IP) and `-w 0` (don't wait for ping) should speed up the scan a lot.

Comment: This doesn't really do the same thing.  The `route get` commands the original posted mentions perform a lookup in the local routing table and return the result.  For example, you can ask `ip route get 192.168.1.32/28` to find which routing table entry will be used for that network, but you can't ask `tracert` about network blocks.

Comment: @Hello71 `-w 0` is not working in my case (gives error `Bad value for option -w.`). `-w 1` works however.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. `tracert` doesn't give the routing information such as which interface is being used.

Answer (score 74):

In Powershell:

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress "10.0.0.34" | Select-Object ifIndex,InterfaceAlias,DestinationPrefix,NextHop,RouteMetric -Last 1

ifIndex           : 10
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet 2
DestinationPrefix : 10.64.0.0/10
NextHop           : 0.0.0.0
RouteMetric       : 0
```

Comment: tbh this should be upvoted more. `Find-NetRoute` is probably the closest you're going to get to `ip route get` on Windows.

Comment: Note that this will not work on Windows 7 (and lower). Should work on Windows 8 (and above).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Btw, powershell seems not designed for daily interactive use ...

Answer (score 18):

The `pathping` command is similar to `tracert` but includes the outgoing interface.

Using cygwin, this command gives the outgoing IP/interface for a particular destination (specified by `$HOST`):

`pathping -n -w 1 -h 1 -q 1 $HOST | head -n 4 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: This is a better answer.

`pathping -n -w 1 -h 1 -q 1 $HOST`

was also very informative for me.  Helped me figure out a problem I was having.

Comment: An alternative that doesn't depend on output appearing on line 4 exactly: `pathping.exe -n -w 1 -h 1 -q 1 $HOST | grep -Pom1 '^\s+0\s+\K[\d\.]+'`. This matches on the first hop (has a `0` prefix)