# OpenVPN alongside L2TP VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, windows-networking

I'm using NordVPN on my Windows computer (which I believe is just OpenVPN under the hood) and I would also like to use my work's L2TP VPN at the same time. For my work VPN I only have a couple of persistent routes tho specific IPs that I use for work, but these routes, of course, don't work while connected to NordVPN.

Is there anyway change these routes so they work while the NordVPN is on? Thanks.

route table with both VPNs connected:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.100.1    192.168.100.5     25
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.8.1       10.8.8.160      3
         10.8.8.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.8.8.160    259
       10.8.8.160  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.8.160    259
       10.8.8.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.8.160    259
    34.202.xx.xx  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.134      2
    89.249.64.230  255.255.255.255    192.168.100.1    192.168.100.5     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.8.1       10.8.8.160      3
   151.181.76.114  255.255.255.255         10.8.8.1       10.8.8.160      4
    192.168.100.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.100.5    281
    192.168.100.5  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.100.5    281
  192.168.100.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.100.5    281
  192.168.128.134  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.128.134    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.100.5    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.8.8.160    259
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   192.168.128.134    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.100.5    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.8.160    259
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.128.134    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
    34.202.xx.xx  255.255.255.255    192.168.100.1       1
===========================================================================
```

Ipconfig:

```
PPP adapter SecondVPN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.128.134
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd00::1
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::806d:3fd0:8c05:a42%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.8.160
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b9d3:da3:a5c0:38c5%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.5
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%3
                                       192.168.100.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Figure out how NordVPN sets routes with `ip route` (if it's OpenVPN, probably two /1 routes so it can keep the default route), and modify the route table to make it work again (which may mean deleting the two /1 routes, adding a default route instead, and adding your L2TP VPN routes if they got deleted).

And *of course* you can have several VPNs, if the IP range is clearly defined.

**Edit**

The following are the /1 routes I mentioned:

```
      0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.8.1       10.8.8.160      3
    128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.8.1       10.8.8.160      3
```

You see they are identical, and both together act in the same way as `default` (which would be /0), but they are more specific, so they override `default`. Your original `default` route is

```
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.100.1    192.168.100.5     25
```

The two active+persistent routes to 34.202.xx.xx are /32 routes to a single machine (netmask 255.255.255.255), I'm not sure if this is correct

```
34.202.xx.xx  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.128.134      2
```

So this would mean 192.168.100.0/24 on `Ethernet` is your home network connection, 10.8.8.0/24 on `Ethernet 2` is the NordVPN, and `192.168.128.134/32` on `PPP` is the single-address endpoint of the L2TP VPN, is that correct? And the single machine on the L2TP VPN you want to reach is 34.202.xx.xx?

The routes look like they *should* work for that. Please edit question with output of `tracert 34.202.xx.xx` (edit results in a suitable way), or use one of the methods from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/346347/on-windows-how-to-determine-route-for-ip-destination) question, if the `tracert` output is not informative enough.

Comment: NordVPN uses a TAP connection. So I don't see any specific routes for that VPN. I still see my routes for my work VPN though.

Comment: No matter if it's tun or tap, you'll have *some* routes. These *won't* be specific for that VPN, but general enough so nearly all traffic goes through that VPN (which is exactly what you don't want). If you can't figure it out yourself, please edit question with a description of the network interface setup and where the tap interface is bridged to, if it is, and add output of `ip route`.

Comment: I added the outputs so you can see what I have. I even lowered the metric on the interface, but still no luck.

Comment: Thanks. This new explanation is what I assumed as well. It looks like it should work but doesn't. I'll try to get the server admin to allow pings on this server so I can tracert.

Comment: Welp, the tracert doesn't work. I just get "General failure." for every ping.  Thanks for the help though. I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: "General failure" looks odd, this suggests the problem is somewhere else, not with the route. Please try the "Find-NetRoute" with PowerShell, as described in the linked question. This shouldn't do pings, but just look at the route, AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry, it just shows the next hop, but that will always be the gateway (192.168.100.1  )

Comment: It *should* show "192.168.128.134", where it would get encapsulated in an L2TP package. At least that's how it works on Linux, I haven't tried L2TP on Windows yet. Next thing I'd do is disable NordVPN, and see if you get different results for tracert and Find-NetRoute.

Comment: Still the same thing for those trace route commands :/

Comment: I'm starting to get confused now. I thought the problem was that you couldn't get it to work while NordVPN is active? Now it looks like it doesn't even work without NordVPN. What is a good configuration, where you can reach your work's L2TP VPN? How does this configuration look like, what do tracert/Find-NetRoute show for these? If you can reach your work's VPN, tracert *should* work. If it doesn't, then the next step is to look *very* closely at how the L2TP VPN is set up.

Comment: The L2TP VPN works when NordVPN is off with the above configuration. Traceroute for some reason does not work even with the NordVPN off - not even one hop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76640/discussion-between-trevor-arjeski-and-dirkt).

Answer (score -1):

More then one VPN client on a End User machine is usually not supported. You will need to use one VPN connection at a time.